# About the correctness of focal Lengths, sensor Height, sensor Width taken with Android Camerax

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-camera2, android-camerax

with the android camerax, I get the focalLengths, hFov, vFov , cameraSensorHeight and cameraSensorWidth values from the corresponding camera of the phone as follows.

```
    val maxFocus = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_INFO_AVAILABLE_FOCAL_LENGTHS)
    val size = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_PHYSICAL_SIZE)
    val hFov = Math.toDegrees((2 * atan((size.width / (maxFocus[0] * 2)).toDouble())))
    val vFov = Math.toDegrees((2 * atan((size.height / (maxFocus[0] * 2)).toDouble())))
    val focalLengths = maxFocus[0]
    val sensorHeight = size.height
    val sensorWidth = size.width
```

When I talked to people who are interested in photography, they said that the pictures taken in 4:3 ratio are not correct on every phone with this data. I am wondering about the veracity of this issue.

What is the accuracy rate of this data I receive for each device? For example, in the values I have taken in this way: Can I return an incorrect result for the wide-angle camera? If there is something wrong, is there a better approach? Thanks

Comment: Interesting. If you send an email to camerax-developers@android.com, someone will be able to answer this.

Comment: Those values are for the sensor size, not the picture size. This is because not all pixels of the sensor are used to take a picture, it depends on many factors.